# Don't destroy on load

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make an 2D RPG game which has a lot object that I use don'tdestroyonload script. But then I want to destroy it when I return to main menu.

I have tried this script

```
SceneManager.activeSceneChanged += DestroyOnMenuScreen;

private void DestroyOnMenuScreen(Scene oldScene, Scene newScene)
{
    if (newScene.buildIndex == menuScreenBuildIndex)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

So that means the don't destroy on load object will be destroyed when I move to main menu, but the problem is when I want to play again, it will show me that it can't find the object which mean it has been destroyed completely.

Is there a way to make sure that the object return as before when I load the game again? I tried using `gameObject.setActive(false);` but when I died and load the game again, it stays still at the gameover state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you have scenes as:

- Menu => Contains Menu object
- Scene1 => Contains Manager object
- Scene2
- Scene3

You want the `DontDestroyOnLoad` to work on Scene1 and Scene2/3 but removed on Menu. 
Navigation is such that you always move from Menu to Scene1.

Have your `DontDestroyOnLoad` object in Scene1.

Then in the `Menu` have destroy process:

```
public class Menu : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start()
    {
        Destroy(FindObjectOfType<Manager>());
    }
}

public class Manager : MonoBehaviour
{
      private static Manager instance = null;

      private void Awake()
      {
          if (instance == null)
          { 
               instance = this;
               DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
               return;
          }
          if (instance == this) return; 
          Destroy(gameObject);
      }
}
```

Your manager needs a singleton style pattern. When you get back to Scene1 a new instance of the object will be added and you need to make sure the original stays but the new one gets removed.

The Main class will check if a Manager can be found. On first run, nothing happens but during play, if you get back to Menu then the manager is found and removed. Next time you get back to Scene1 a new Manager is created since it is part of the scene.

Comment: Thanks for the help :3